# How do deployment slot settings work on an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-configuration, azure-deployment-slots

For a given web app service, when multiple deployment slots are setup, e.g.:

`myapp`

`myapp/staging`

and I create an appSetting that is marked as a "deployment slot setting" on `myapp`, what happens when I swap slots? Does the deployment slot setting stay with `myapp` or does it move to `myapp/staging`?

Also, what happens if I mix and match deployment slot settings and non-deployment slot settings between deployment slots?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Marking a setting as a "deployment slot setting" keeps it sticky to that particular deployment slot - e.g. an app setting marked as a "deployment slot setting" on `myapp` will always stick with `myapp` and will never move to `myapp/staging` during a swap. If the setting is not set as a deployment slot setting, it will move from `myapp` to `myapp/staging` during a swap.

AppSettings are NOT shared or synced across deployment slots. If you want an app setting on more than one slot, you need to add it to all of the slots in question with the same value (assuming you *want* the same value across all slots).

In terms of mixing & matching whether or not a given app setting is a deployment slot setting, Azure won't let you do this - it's last in wins. For example, if you have an app setting named `myAppSetting` that is present on more than one slot and you mark it as a deployment slot setting on any one of them, it will be changed to a deployment slot on the others as well, and vice versa. Worth noting that there's no warning or error message when you do this, it just happens silently.